# Match multi-index in parallel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two DataFrames, count, and percentage with the same columns. count has a multi-level index. I want to use `percentage.set_index(....)` to make the index of percentage match the index of count. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`percentage.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])`

to make the same columns be the index, but the two tables won't nessecarily have the same index values or sorting. If you if you want to make sure `percentage` has exactly the same index as `count`, then after that you can also do

`percentage.reindex(count.index)`

but note that you'll end up with null values in your data for any index values that are in `count` but not `percentage`, and you'll throw away any rows of `percentage` where the index value doesn't show up in `count.

Edit:
If you want to do this but don't already know the names of the index columns, you can get them with `count.index.names`.

Comment: I know about set_index, but the problem is that I don't know 'col1' , 'col2', I need to get that from count... I don't need the order to be the same. I just need the columns to be the same column names. percentage is actually a sub-set of count, so some rows in count won't be in percentage. I just need the column names.

Comment: Ah, you can get the names of the index columns in `count`, assuming they have names, with `count.index.names`.

Comment: Thanks. Please add this to your solution so I can accept it!